# Error when creating DevOps project on Azure: Cores quota have ran out in this region, kindly choose a different region or VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When I try to create a DevOps project described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-aks, I get the below error message which apparently hasn't been grammarly checked! I tried different regions and lowered the number of nodes to 1 but I still got the error.

> Cores quota have ran out in this region, kindly choose a different
>   region or VM which requires lesser cores.

Comment: The best is to go to https://dev.azure.com and create the project there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are setting deploy your project to VM. The error should be caused by your **Cores Quota Limit**. You need first go **Subscription**--> **Usage + quotas** of Azure Portal to check the limit about your different region.

[image]

In fact, [vCPU quotas for virtual machines and virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) scale sets are enforced at two tiers for each subscription, in each region. The first tier is the Total Regional vCPUs limit (across all VM Series), and the second tier is the per VM Series vCPUs limit. If you exceed either of these, you will not be allowed to do VM deployment.

On the **Usages + quotas** page, you can search the current quota of your chosen region by using the Quota + Usage filters. And you will see current usage and quota limit values are displayed at the end of the row.

If you need request increase to finish your deployment, just click upper right button. Here has detailed steps you can refer: [Request Increase](https://incredibuild.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IUM/pages/702218274/Setting+the+Core+Quota+of+an+Azure+Region)